# Bond Change in Absolute or Relatively Percentage

Tags: fixed-income, bond, duration

Since most of the bonds prices are quoted in price, for example, bond price of 103 means 103% of the principal or face value (ex. $1000). Suppose a bond has modified duration of 4.62 years. If yield to maturity increase by 1%, bond price will decrease by 4.62% (0.01*-4.62*100%), so should the bond price be :
1. 103*(1+4.62%)
OR
2. 103+4.62

If we express modified duration using mathematical formula, should it be $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}*\frac{1}{\ P}$ or $\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$

Note: $P$ is bond price in percentage;
$y$ is yield to maturity

Comment: Modified duration is a percentage. So your first formula is correct. Please note that it is percentage change in full price, so make sure to add accrued interest. Absolute $ price change (your second formula) is often referred to as dP/dY or “Risk” on Bloomberg. If you multiply by position size it is DV100. Both are important measures depending on the use. Derivatives quote the second way since they can have a price of 0 or near zero, meaning a percentage statistic would be undefined.

Comment: @Bondwiz, really appreciate it!